# import cv2 on centos 64 bit

Tags: linux, python-2.7, opencv, centos6

I already copy the cv2 and complete the procedure installing opencv and python and I also think the default python installation is usr/lib64/python2.7 and there is also usr/lib/python2.7 and I also move the cv2 using copy -r usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so to usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/ it successfully move but when I run the $python

> > import cv2 [this is what happen[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAWp1.png)

am still wondering if there is a default directory for centos 64 bit or i did wrong on my steps? I followed this tutorial http://techieroop.com/install-opencv-in-centos/ and i find it simple and fast yet im still stuck installing opencv

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and follow the guidelines there to improve your question with sufficient information to describe and reproduce your problem. so, update the question with Traceback instead put a link..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following

```
yum install numpy opencv*
yum check-update
```

then

```
import cv2
print cv2.__version__
```